# jQuery .children() not working in ie6

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, internet-explorer-6

I have a nice tabs script. it's working fine! But. Not in ie6. I can't understand why.

I think that

```
var currentTab = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
```

line is not working in ie6. But again: why?

Need help.

http://jsfiddle.net/sRCfQ/

**UPDATED:**

This solution works:

```
var currentTab = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
```

replace with

```
var currentTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

Don't know why this answer was deleted.

Comment: No, it's IE6 that's not working which is a known problem.btw,you haven't closed the article tag properly in your fiddle

Comment: Does http://jsfiddle.net/sRCfQ/2/ work?

Comment: @toon, are you using CSS3PIE for curves on the tabs ? or some other code that might be altering your HTML ?

Comment: Why are you using IE6?  Even [Microsoft](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) wants people to stop using it!

Answer (score 4):

You are using HTML5 elements like `article` and `section` and these tags are not supported by IE6. You might need to use html5 shiv/shim libraries for that..

Using http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/ fixes the issue for me (*tested on IE7 which was also not working with the jsfiddle*).

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/sRCfQ/3/

---

Also why do you think that line of code is failing.. did you alert the returned value ? (*if so in what way was it wrong?*)

Lastly, but maybe most importantly, do you ***really*** have to support IE6 ?